# Why Does socket.io-client Force Polling in React Native

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io-client with react native and I am getting strange behaviour. I am using socket.io-client version 2.3.0 with react native version 37.0.1, I also have react-navigation library in my project. When I try to use socket.io-client with my flask_socketio server online my app defaults to polling as primary transport even tho in initiating the connection I add transports: ["websocket"]. My app also doesn't work as if it were on my local server. The app for some reason is temperamental. Sometimes it works if I continuously restart the app and I get the websockets to work in the expected behaviour (I am sending messages back and forth i.e. instant messaging). Any ideas?
Code I use to connect

```
UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    let socketio = io("wss://domain.com/namespace", {
      transports: ["websocket"],
      pingTimeout: 30000,
      jsonp: false,
    });
    this.setState({
      socket: socketio.connect(),
    });
  }
```

EDIT:
I'm also getting these warnings in yellow box: 
1. Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground.
2. Unrecognized WebSocket connection option(s) `agent`, `perMessageDeflate`, `pfx`, `key`, `passphrase`, `cert`, `ca`, `ciphers`, `rejectUnauthorized`. Did you mean to put these under `headers`?

Comment: I am having similar issues. For what it's worth can you add  `socketio.on('connect', () => console.log('connected: ', socketio.id));` and see if you get a connected log? I get that but nothing after for any events

Comment: After a bit of testing I realized that flask_socketio which is my server being run by gunicorn and proxied by nginx cannot run on multiple process with gunicorn. It's as if the clients were all connecting to different processes on my server which all acted as different instances of the same room since the processes could not communicate with each other. I set gunicorn to 1 worker process and that solved my problem for now.